# Using Pyaudio to Play Wave Data in an Array

Tags: python, numpy, pyaudio

I'm trying to define a class that will, among other things, read a wavefile into a numpy array and then play it.  It looks like the callback function is only getting called once, so I'm guessing whatever mechanism is used to "keep the stream" active isn't working?

Has anyone successfully done this?

```
class asoa_io:

  def write_callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    print "Frame count is " + str(frame_count)
    list_data = self.template_wave[self.template_idx:(self.template_idx+frame_count) - 1]
    data = list_data.tobytes()
    print repr(data)
    self.template_idx += frame_count
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)


  def read_callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    self.signal += in_data  # This has the incoming signal as a list of frames.
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

  """ Synthesize the speech and do any preprocessing.
  Note that we want to use the kal_diphone voice for synthesis.
  """
  def __init__(self, text_string):
    temp_fd, template_file = tempfile.mkstemp()
    string_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()


    string_file.write(text_string)
    string_file.flush()


    if (subprocess.call([PATH_TO_TEXT2WAVE, string_file.name, "-o", template_file]) > 0):
        print "Error running text2wave"

    string_file.close()


    self.template_rate, self.template_wave = scipy.io.wavfile.read(template_file)
    self.template_length = len(self.template_wave)
    self.template_framesize = 100

    self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
#        self.input_stream =     self.pa.open(format=pyaudio.get_format_from_width(2),
#                                    channels=1, rate = self.template_rate, input=True,
#                                    stream_callback = self.read_callback)
    self.output_stream = self.pa.open(format=pyaudio.get_format_from_width(2),
                                 channels=1, rate = self.template_rate, output=True,
                                 stream_callback = self.write_callback)

    self.template_idx = 0
    self.signal = []


  def start_speech(self):
    self.output_stream.start_stream()
#        self.input_stream.start_stream()
    while self.output_stream.is_active():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    time.sleep(10)

  def stop(self):
    self.output_stream.stop_stream()
    self.input_stream.stop_stream()
    self.output_stream.close()
    self.input_stream.close()
    self.pa.terminate()
```

For what it's worth, I copied the sample callback code from the pyaudio documentation site and used it to play the wave file that's being read in; that worked fine.  The first 1024 byte also look right.

Thanks for any help anyone can give!